# Dev c++ expected `;' before "to", expected `)' before ';' token

Tags: c++

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int SIZE = 10;
    int NUMBERS[SIZE];
    int i;
    int j;
    int temp;

    for((i = 0) to (SIZE - 2))
    {
           for((j = 0) to (SIZE - 2))
           {
                  if(NUMBERS[j] < NUMBERS[j + 1])
                  {
                  temp = NUMBERS[j]
                  NUMBERS[j] = NUMBERS[j+1]
                  NUMBERS[j+1] = temp
                  }
           }
    }

    cout << "Sorted list";
    cout << "===========";

    for((i = 0) to (SIZE - 1))
    {
        cout << "Number ", i + 1, ": ", NUMBERS[i]
    }


    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I keep getting:

> line 18 & 34: expected `;' before "to"
>   line 32: expected`)' before ';' token

I can't figure out why.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `SIZE` should be `const size_t SIZE = 10;`

Comment: `for((i = 0) to (SIZE - 1))` that's not valid c++ syntax.

Comment: Where did you learn `for((i = 0) to (SIZE - 2))` is the correct syntax for a [for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed some `;` in the code (and a few others). Try this version:

```
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int SIZE = 10;
    int NUMBERS[SIZE];

    int temp;

    for(int i = 0; i< SIZE - 2; i++)
    {
           for(int j = 0; j < SIZE - 2; j++)
           {
                  if(NUMBERS[j] < NUMBERS[j + 1])
                  {
                  temp = NUMBERS[j];
                  NUMBERS[j] = NUMBERS[j+1];
                  NUMBERS[j+1] = temp;
                  }
           }
    }

    cout << "Sorted list";
    cout << "===========";

    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE - 1; i++)
    {
        cout << "Number ", i + 1, ": ", NUMBERS[i];
    }


    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Please consider that you should initialize the `NUMBERS`.

Comment: sorry @πάνταῥεῖ , now I realized, they may be other things that I missed

Comment: I'm afraid there's no way to give a concise answer to fix all the errors in the code, (with explanations) nor I think this question would be useful for any future research. We should get rid of that question in whole, I've been voting to close it.

Comment: Thank you for the help. But now I'm getting expected primary-expression before ')' token and expected `;' before ')' token for line 19.

Comment: @dmortiz try again now.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! I've been working on 3 different codes for hours and that was the only one I could not get on my own.

Answer (score -1):

Try :

```
for(i = 0; i <= (SIZE - 2); i++)
{
       for(j = 0; j<=(SIZE - 2); j++)
       {
              if(NUMBERS[j] < NUMBERS[j + 1])
              {
              temp = NUMBERS[j];
              NUMBERS[j] = NUMBERS[j+1];
              NUMBERS[j+1] = temp;
              }
       }
}
cout << "Sorted list";
cout << "===========";

for(int i = 0; i <= SIZE - 1; i++)
{
    cout << "Number ", (i + 1), ": ", NUMBERS[i];
}
system("PAUSE");
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

Comment: didn't see the semicolon's were missing. Thanks oreo.